# Displaying an XML file with XSL within an existing webpage

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to get an html page to display an XML file formatted with an XSL stylesheet. Whatever examples I see are either displaying it in a new page, with the XSL stylesheet taking care of the  tags, but no examples where I can clearly see it being displayed as part of an existing webpage...

I'm using a PHP script to generate the HTML. And the XML data is being generated by another PHP function (not under my control). The XSL file is uploaded on the server and stored at: /xsl/1234567890.xsl

Here's what the php outputs:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xsl/1234567890.xsl"?>
...
<xml tags>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to transform the XML:

**1 browser**
Most browsers implement XSLT processors. You could use:

```
<iframe src="xml-source.xml"/>
```

The users will have to make three requests (page, xml, xsl) and unless you want inline scrollbars you'll need some Javascript to resize the `iframe`.

**2 server**
You can run a XSLT processor on the server side and return the transformed XML. There are many ways to do this, here is one [in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php). With caching you shouldn't run into any performance problems and also support browsers without internal XSLT processors (e.g. mobile devices).

Comment: Thanks Josef! I am attempting the XSLTProcessor() approach!